# Incorrect state value?

Tags: reactjs, sockets, socket.io

The code below is a chat client (using socket.io). After the user sends a message (event 'usr_input'), the server responds with a 'message' event. The messages are being recieved (console.log(msg)) , a copy of the array is created ([...chatMessages]) and array of messages is updated. However, when the function is called again the value is incorrect (I see that the copy of the chat messages has the new message appended, but the class state is an empty array). However the state has updated (verified using useEffect).

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles/chat.css";
import { uuidv4 } from "./utils/utils";
const SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:3337";
const io = require("socket.io-client");


function ChatManager(props) {
  // How to handle sockets (where do we store them)
  const [UId, setUId] = useState("");
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
  const [chatMessages, setChatMessages] = useState([]);
  const [role, setRole] = useState("Role");
  const useForceUpdate = () => useState()[1];
  function displayMessage(msg) {
    if (UId) {
      if (msg.user === UId) {
        return (
          <article class="msg-container msg-self" id="msg-0">
            <div class="msg-box">
              <div class="flr">
                <div class="messages">
                  <p class="msg" id="msg-0">
                    {msg.message}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <article class="msg-container msg-remote" id="msg-0">
            <div class="msg-box">
              <div class="flr">
                <div class="messages">
                  <p class="msg" id="msg-0">
                    {msg.message}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
        );
      }
    }
  }

  function addMessage(msg) {
    console.log("message: ");
    console.log(msg);
    const newMessages = [...chatMessages];
    console.log(chatMessages);
    newMessages.push(msg);
    console.log(newMessages);
    setChatMessages(newMessages);
    console.log("Message added");

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("did mount");
    if (!socket) {
      setUId(uuidv4());
      console.log("Set UId");
      setSocket(io.connect(SERVER_URL));
      console.log("Socket mounted");
    } else {
      console.log("Socket emit");

      socket.emit("join", {
        uid: UId,
        tid: "Task ID, add later",
        role: role
      });

      socket.on("error", function(err) {
        console.log("received socket error:");
        console.log(err);
      });

      socket.on("message", function(msg) {
     addMessage(msg);
      });
    }
    return () => {
      console.log("Unmounting");
      if (socket) {
        socket.emit("leave", {
          uid: UId,
          tid: "Task ID, add later",
          role: role
        });
        console.log("Leaving message sent");
      }
    };
  }, [socket]);

  function sendMessage() {
    const msg = "Test message";
    socket.emit("usr_input", {
      uid: UId,
      tid: "Task ID, add later",
      message: msg,
      role: role
    });

    console.log("Message sent");
  }

return (
    <div>
      <h1> Here is the chatbox </h1>
      <ChatBox 
      sendMessage={sendMessage} 
      chatMessages={chatMessages}
      displayMessage={displayMessage}/>
      <h1> EOF </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

function ChatBox(props) {
  return (
    <section class="chatbox">
      <section id="chat-messages" class="chat-window">
        {props.chatMessages.map( (msg) => {props.displayMessage(msg)})}
      </section>

    <form class="chat-input" onsubmit="return false;">
        <input
          type="text"
          id="message"
          autocomplete="on"
          placeholder="Type a message"
        />
        <button type="button" onClick={props.sendMessage}>
          <svg
            style={{
              width: "24px",
              height: "24px"
            }}
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          >
            {" "}
            <path
              fill="rgba(0,0,0,.38)"
              d="M17,12L12,17V14H8V10H12V7L17,12M21,16.5C21,16.88 20.79,17.21 20.47,17.38L12.57,21.82C12.41,21.94 12.21,22 12,22C11.79,22 11.59,21.94 11.43,21.82L3.53,17.38C3.21,17.21 3,16.88 3,16.5V7.5C3,7.12 3.21,6.79 3.53,6.62L11.43,2.18C11.59,2.06 11.79,2 12,2C12.21,2 12.41,2.06 12.57,2.18L20.47,6.62C20.79,6.79 21,7.12 21,7.5V16.5M12,4.15L5,8.09V15.91L12,19.85L19,15.91V8.09L12,4.15Z"
            />{" "}
          </svg>{" "}
        </button>
      </form>
    </section>
  );
}
```

I've tried forcing an update by calling useState, but got this error (https://dev.to/ranewallin/js-bites-react-hook-is-called-in-a-function-which-is-neither-a-react-function-or-sic-a-custom-react-hook-1g2c).

Any suggestions or ideas to test would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Changed title and text based on new info.

Comment: if `console.log(newMessages)` indeed gives you the correct output then I'm not convinced your state doesn't update. Please confirm with `useEffect(() => {console.log('chatMessages state:', chatMessages)}, [chatMessages])`

Comment: That’s clever! You’re right that it is updating, however chatMessages appears to be an empty array when addMessage is called.. Is it possibly a scope issue?